# How to render images inside flextable in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, flextable

I'm trying to render image inside `flextable` within a  `rmarkdown` which on render gives word document.

Sample `rmarkdown` code:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: word_document
params:
  img_path1: Excel whole.png
---
```

```
library(officer)
library(flextable)
library(kableExtra)
```

```
virus_summary <- data.frame(
  Task = "Word Table",
  "Completion Date" = as.character(format(Sys.Date(), '%B %d, %Y')),
   stringsAsFactors = FALSE
 )

 img_object <- as_image(src = "./Excel whole.png", width = 1)



 virus_tbl <- virus_summary |>
   flextable() |>
   compose(
     j = "Task",
     i = 1,
     value = as_paragraph(
       as_chunk("\n"),
       as_chunk("Word Table"),
       as_chunk("\n"),
       as_chunk("\n"),
       img_object
    )
   ) |>
  border_remove() |>
   hline(part = "all", border = fp_border(color="black")) |>
   vline(border = fp_border(color="black")) |>
   vline_left(border = fp_border(color="black")) |>
   hline_top(part = "all", border = fp_border(color="black")) |>
   bold(bold = TRUE, part = "header") |>
   width(width = 7.9, j = 1,unit = "cm") |>
   width(width = 6.5, j = 2,unit = "cm") |>
   padding(padding = 10, part = "all")

 virus_tbl
```

In here you can use any image as you want.

**Problem:**
When I run the code chunk only the **image path** is showing up instead of the image inside the table and same while knitting the `rmarkdown` into word document.

Output of above code:
[Output Table](https://imgur.com/a/2lnmbZz)

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get an error while running your script because source parameter for image of `flextable::as_image()` is `src` and not `x`. With kableExtra, there is also a function named `as_image()`, solution is to use the following:

```
img_object <- flextable::as_image(src = img.file, width = 1)
```

Without the conflicts that could happen with kableExtra, another point is that images in flextable can not be outputed with `rmarkdown::word_document()`, it must be processed with officedown. See the note in `as_image()` documentation:

> This chunk option requires package officedown in a R Markdown context with Word output format.

Comment: Table generated from `kable` will be an image file  and not as a table like `flextable()` right